# Most appropriate data type to use?

Tags: c#, winforms, validation, datetime

I am creating a C# forms application and on that application needs to be an input box of some sort for users to type in a time in the format hh:mm:ss. This also needs to be able to be validated so that users cannot enter anything other than numbers, but also validated so that the hour has to be between 0-24, minutes between 0-60 and seconds between 0-60.

Someone suggested using three different text boxes (One for hours, minutes and seconds) but this, to me, seems archaic and more hassle than it's worth for validation as well.

I need to be able to use a statement to basically say `if time is below 24:00:00, do x`

Am I right in assuming `DateTime` would be best in this scenario? I'm asking as I'm not 100% sure since I've never really used `DateTime` before, only read about it.

Thank you.

Comment: Yes.  You probably want `DateTime.TryParseExact` which allows you to specify the exact format the string should be in.

Comment: For a time span you have another option: TimeSpan. Of course this will just help you to parse it but remember: it's not locale aware and it won't help user to enter proper text (because it's just a string) so you may need a masked edit (unless you want to use a custom control).

Comment: Is there any documentation that would be particularly helpful in using the `DateTime` option as well as validation involved with it?

Answer (score 3):

If you're happy to take a dependency on a 3rd party library, I'd suggest using the date/time library I maintain: [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org). Unlike the .NET framework, it has a type specifically for a "time without a date" - [`LocalTime`](http://nodatime.org/api/html/T_NodaTime_LocalTime.htm).

You can use a [`LocalTimePattern`](http://nodatime.org/api/html/T_NodaTime_Text_LocalTimePattern.htm) to convert between a `LocalTime` and `string` representations.

If you want to stick to the BCL, then either `DateTime` or `TimeSpan` will *work* - but neither type actually describes the kind of value you're trying to represent.

Comment: It's a pretty nice library (especially because it abstracts many concept) but...I wonder why it lacks of many common **operations on intervals** (intersection, union, merge, and so on) and concept of **list of intervals** (with related operations). Yes, not so tricky to implement but library seems reasonably complete!

Comment: @Adriano: `Interval` itself is actually a type I'd like to remove if possible; currently it only operates between `Instant` values, and I suspect that the business requirements for such a type are pretty varied. I'd rather not have a type than implement the wrong thing, and be stuck with it for a long time.

Comment: I agree requirements may vary a lot but I saw _custom_ half working implementation of that type so often that I pray for an _official_ implementation. Even with just few basic operations...

Comment: @Adriano: There's nothing "official" about Noda Time :) I do take your point, but if everyone has different requirements then it doesn't actually help to implement something else. If we hear similar requirements multiple times, we'll certainly do what we can.

Comment: @John: I'm relatively new to C# so I haven't experimented with 3rd party libraries. If I used a 3rd party library such as yours, would I have issues when moving my project from my home computer to a computer on university campus bearing in mind I'm not sure if I can download and use libraries there due to the restrictions placed on the machines by the admins.

Comment: Of course I understand your point, more than a _feature request_ it was curiosity. BTW...anything you write becomes official and de-facto standard! ;)

Comment: @user2929108: You'd have to ask with the admins, to be honest. If you can't move a binary from your home machine to university, and you can't download it from the web site, then that would be a problem. You could potentially fetch the source and build that of course... but if you're new to C# you might be better off with the BCL types, inappropriate though they are for this.